# How makefile sends `is up to date` for target inside a folder?

Tags: makefile

My `makefile` has a target for `.env`, which will simply create a `.env` file. When the file already exists, I will receive *make: `.env' is up to date.*

The `makefile` is like:

```
.env: .env.sample
    @echo "  ⚠️  Preparing local configuration..."
    @test -f .env && echo "$$DOTENV_ERROR" && exit 1 || true
    @cp .env.sample .env
```

However, I would like the same behaviour for a file inside a folder. Like:

```
./config/config.json: ./config/config.json.sample
    @echo "  ⚠️  Preparing local configuration..."
    @test -f ./config/config.json && echo "$$CONFIGJSON_ERROR" && exit 1 || true
    @cp config/config.json.sample config/config.json
```

Instead of receiving *make: './config/config.json' is up to date.* I receive my `CONFIGJSON_ERROR`, I would like to receive the same `.env` message, saying that the file is up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a misunderstanding: make will invoke a recipe if either of *two* situations happens.  The first is that the target file does not exist.  That seems to be the one you're relying on above.

The second is if at least one of the prerequisites is newer than the target.  In your recipe you'll fail if that happens because the target exists already but the target is out of date.  That appears to be what's happening here: the target `config/config.json` exists but `config/config.json.sample` is newer than it.

I don't really understand why you're trying to throw an error in this situation so it's hard to suggest an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, you were really helpful.
But, I didn't quite understand you. What do you mean by 
> "the target config/config.json exists but config/config.json.sample is newer than it."
the file `config/config.json`, but the file `config/config.json.sample` also exists ?

Comment: Yes.  Both of those files exist.  If you get the error, that means that `test -f ./config/config.json` succeeds.  It will succeed if the `./config/config.json` file exists (that's what `test -f` does: it sees if the file exists and succeeds if it does and fails if it doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure of what behavior you're after, but I'll take a guess...

Make will rebuild your target if the target does not exist, or any of its dependencies are newer than the target.   So in your case, I'm guessing `./config/config.json.sample` is likely newer than `./config/config.json`.   If you want to not copy, even if the .sample file is newer, then you could use an [order only](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) prerequisite:

```
./config/config.json: | ./config/config.json.sample
     ...
```

The result would be that `.config/config.json` would only be rebuilt if it does not exist (assuming it has no other dependencies).  If neither file existed, then `./config/config.json.sample` would be built before `./config/config.json`.